# Unexpected error in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new in react-native, creating a demo for learning. I am getting error in line no. 11 of my DataDetail file **DataDetail.js Unexpected token (11:2)**. Below is the code for my DataDetail file.

```
1. //DataDetail.js
2. 
3. import React from 'react';
4. import {Text,View} from 'react-native';
5. 
6. const DataDetail = (props) => {
7.  return (
8.    <View>
9.      <Text>{props.objData.title}</Text>
10.    </View>>
11.  );
12. };
13. 
14. export default DataDetail;
```

I am calling this from my Component:

```
import DataDetail from './DataDetail';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text,View} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Home extends Component<Props> {

state = {arrData:[]};

componentWillMount(){
  axios.get('https://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts')
  .then(response => this.setState({arrData:response.data}));
}

renderList(){
  return this.state.arrData.map(data => <DataDetail key={data.id} objData={data} />);
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.renderList()}
    </View>
  );
}
}
```

Can anyone help me here to understand, what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: You have an extra arrow in your JSX `<View>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had 2 `>` when closing the `View` tag.

```
6. const DataDetail = (props) => {
7.  return (
8.    <View>
9.      <Text>{props.objData.title}</Text>
10.    </View>
11.  );
12. };
```

Comment: Ohhh Thanks Man.. I lost my 30 mins in that silly mistake. Is there any way to check this typos in editor itself.

Comment: Use a linter such [Eslint](https://eslint.org/). It can be easily plugabble in multiple editors.

Comment: I am using flex with nuclide... ESLint having multiple issues with rules and config

Comment: You can customize which rules to apply by Eslint if you don't want to use defaults or any defined styled by default such airbnb one.